# elfinder - copy hardlinks

Tags: nginx, file-manager, elfinder

We move alot of big files and this work flawlessly because this is done in a instance without copying the file. (just moving the pointer)

But sometimes we need acces to the same file from multiple locations in the filesystem, today we copy the file but this takes extremely long time and is storage consuming, this is expected since the file is copied to another place on  disk. So we can't complain on this :)

But in our workflow we actually don't have to have multiple files, multiple pointers to the same file is enough. Therefore the hardlink model is perfect choice for us. This would be extremely usefull if it was possible to change the behavior on the copy feature in elfinder, Does anyone know if it is possible. ? :)

Answer (score 0):

It is made possible by extending the elFinderVolumeLocalFileSystem class.

```php
class elFinderVolumeMyLocalFileSystem extends elFinderVolumeLocalFileSystem
{
    protected function _copy($source, $targetDir, $name) {
        $target = $this->_joinPath($targetDir, $name);
        if (! $ret = link($source, $target)) {
            return parent::_copy($source, $targetDir, $name);
        }
        return $ret;
    }
}

$opts = array(
    'locale' => '',
    'roots'  => array(
        array(
            'driver' => 'MyLocalFileSystem',
            'path'   => '/path/to/files/',
            'URL'    => 'http://localhost/to/files/'
        )
    )
);

// run elFinder
$connector = new elFinderConnector(new elFinder($opts));
$connector->run();
```